# display data from 3 tables with conditional joining

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have 3 tables with below format.

```
Table A                    Table B                   Table C   
id                         id1  id2                   id   name
1                          1    null                  1.1  john   
2                          1    1.1                   
                           2    null
```

With the query

```
select a.id,b.id1,b.id2,c.id,c.name 
from TableA a 
join TableB b on a.id = b.id1
left join TableC on b.id2 = c.id
```

I will see the below data

```
a.id  b.id1  b.id2  c.id  c.name
1     1      null   null  null
1     1      1.1    1.1   john
2     2      null   null  null
```

My intention is, I need to get rid of first row in the result set i.e., if there is data then display only not null rows if there is no data then display null row.

Please let me know if you need any clarity.

Comment: What happens if there are multiple non-null values?  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes there is a possibility to have multiple non null values. In that case I need to display all the non null values.

see the below example.

Table A                    Table B                   Table C   
id                         id1  id2                   id   name
1                          1    null                  1.1  john   
2                          1    1.1                   1.2 Gerry
                            1    1.2
                           2    null

Then my result should be:

1  1.1  John
1  1.2  Gerry
2  null  null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have a solution by using another table which store if there is at least on non null value on `id2` for  `id1` in `Tableb`, and if so deletes  when there is the null  values.

This table would be :

```
select sum(case when id2 is null then 0 else 1 end) as test,
id1
from TableB
group by id1
```

And the query :

```
select a.id,b.id1,b.id2,c.id,c.name 
from TableA a 
join TableB b on a.id = b.id1
left join TableC on b.id2 = c.id
left join (
select sum(case when id2 is null then 0 else 1 end) as test,
id1
from TableB
group by id1
) AS Table_test on Table_test.id1 = b.id1

where b.id2 is not null or Table_test.test = 0
```

Thus, in cases where you have multiple rows, you will have all your `id2` in a single row, and no null row, and in only null cases you will keep the null row.

Comment: Executed the same query in oracle sql developer. But getting below error. Please help.

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 11

Comment: Never mind. It is working now, but I have one more concern what if I want to run the query only for particular id.
For example if I want to see the names only for id 1.
i.e., TableA.id='1'.

Please suggest. As I'm new to Oracle I don't know where to add the filter.

Comment: Just change the `WHERE` clause this way :
`WHERE (b.id2 is not null or Table_test.test = 0) and a.id=1`
  Do you understand everything in this query ? If you are new to oracle this query might be more understandable than the one @sgeddes proposed, but the two of them work. And please confrm the answer if it works :)

Comment: Thanks BD01. It worked. Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, here's one option using `rank`:

```
select *
from (
    select a.id,b.id1,b.id2,c.id,c.name,
        rank() over (partition by b.id1 
                       order by case when b.id2 is null then 1 else 0 end) rnk
    from TableA a 
        join TableB b on a.id = b.id1
        left join TableC on b.id2 = c.id
) t
where id2 is not null or rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicates are all coming in from `TableB`.  You can prioritize those rows in several ways.  I think the easiest method for your data is aggregation:

```
select a.id, b.id1, b.id2, c.id, c.name 
from TableA a join
     (select b.id1, max(b.id2) as id2
      from TableB b
      group by b.id1
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id1 left join
     TableC
     on b.id2 = c.id;
```

Comment: I'd probably point out that this assumes the OP only wants to return a single record from `tableb`.  I assumed there could be multiple non-null records in `tableb` that could be returned.

Comment: @sgeddes . . . The question is quite ambiguous on that point and this version does work on the sample data.  The OP should provide more explanation.

Comment: If there are multiple records for one id in table B then we need to display all those non null values.